# Why doesn't Nutch seem to know about "Last-Modified"?

Tags: web-crawler, nutch

I setup Nutch with a db.fetch.interval.default of 60000 so that I can crawl every day.  If I don't, it won't even look at my site when I crawl the next day.  But when I do crawl the next day, every page that it fetched yesterday gets fetched with a 200 response code, indicating that it's not using the previous day's date in the "If-Modified-Since".  Shouldn't it skip fetching pages that haven't changed?  Is there a way to make it do that?  I noticed a ProtocolStatus.NOT_MODIFIED in Fetcher.java, so I think it should be able to do this, shouldn't it?

By the way, this is cut and pasted from conf/nutch-default.xml from the current trunk:

```
<!-- web db properties -->

<property>
  <name>db.default.fetch.interval</name>
  <value>30</value>
  <description>(DEPRECATED) The default number of days between re-fetches of a page.
  </description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>db.fetch.interval.default</name>
  <value>2592000</value>
  <description>The default number of seconds between re-fetches of a page (30 days).
  </description>
</property>
```

Comment: Which version of Nutch are you using?

Comment: I'm using the svn trunk, last updated about 5 days ago.

Comment: svn update
At revision 802613.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the problem.  It's a bug in Nutch.  I've emailed the Nutch developer list about it, but here's my fix:

```
Index: src/plugin/protocol-http/src/java/org/apache/nutch/protocol/http/HttpResponse.java
===================================================================
--- src/plugin/protocol-http/src/java/org/apache/nutch/protocol/http/HttpResponse.java  (revision 802632)
+++ src/plugin/protocol-http/src/java/org/apache/nutch/protocol/http/HttpResponse.java  (working copy)
@@ -124,11 +124,15 @@
         reqStr.append("\r\n");
       }

-      reqStr.append("\r\n");
       if (datum.getModifiedTime() > 0) {
         reqStr.append("If-Modified-Since: " + HttpDateFormat.toString(datum.getModifiedTime()));
         reqStr.append("\r\n");
       }
+      else if (datum.getFetchTime() > 0) {
+          reqStr.append("If-Modified-Since: " + HttpDateFormat.toString(datum.getFetchTime()));
+          reqStr.append("\r\n");
+      }
+      reqStr.append("\r\n");     

       byte[] reqBytes= reqStr.toString().getBytes();
```

Now I'm seeing 304s in my Apache logs where I'm supposed to be seeing them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mistaken with an option name - db.fetch.interval.default. It should be.

**db.default.fetch.interval**

The number of days after each page injected is fetched that it should next be fetched. 30 by default.

I just read change log of the latest version, and found following

> 9. NUTCH-61 - Support for adaptive re-fetch interval and detection of
>      unmodified content. (ab)

If you don't have latest version installed, I suggest you to do that.

Also, are you using -adddays option for crawling?

Comment: What does the -adddays option do?

Comment: It's db.fetch.interval.default (along with db.fetch.interval.max, db.fetch.schedule.class, db.fetch.schedule.adaptive.inc_rate, etc) in nutch-default.xml.  I assume the name is right there, especially since it seems to make a difference when I change it.

Comment: The adddays option advances the clock however many days you specify.

Comment: I'm pretty sure its db.default.fetch.interval.

Comment: db.default.fetch.interval is marked "DEPRECATED" in nutch-default.xml in the trunk.

Comment: Why do I need --adddays when I have db.fetch.interval.default set to 6000 seconds and I'm crawling once a day?